# Visual C++ (CLI) Hex String to Decimal Base 10

Tags: parsing, visual-c++, c++-cli, hex

I have a Hex String "40" that i would like to convert to its Decimal Base 10 value of 64.

I tried:

```
 String^ val = "40";
 Decimal num = Convert::ToDecimal(val);
```

but that doesn't work as i am clearly doing something wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

i'm using Visual c++ (CLI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
String^ val = "40";
Decimal num = Convert::ToInt32(val, 16);
```

Comment: I don't think you can store an `int` directly into a variable of type `decimal`.

Comment: Yes you can. This compiles and runs fine in VS2010.

Comment: Yes of course.  C++/CLI has the implicit conversions.  I was mistakenly thinking about C#.  The question wasn't tagged `c++-cli`, I just did that.

Answer (score 2):

The simple and efficient solution would be:

```
// C#
int num = int.Parse(val, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

// C++
int num = System::Int32::Parse(val, System::Globalization::NumberStyles::HexNumber);
```

Comment: The C++ syntax is: `int num = int::Parse(val, NumberStyles::HexNumber)`

Comment: @Colin: I knew that... but thanks for pointing out I was giving an example in the wrong language.